# Unable to use dash_bio for plotting ideograms due to incorrect Javascript dependency

Tags: django, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to include dash_bio ideogram in my proyect. I have just included in my project a simple ideogram as follows:

```
    dashbio.Ideogram(
        id='ideogram-id',
        chromosomes=['X'],
        orientation='horizontal',
    ),
```

There are no callbacks for this ideogram, I am just trying the simplest example for an indeogram. The error I get on my console when trying to plot it is the following:

`bundle.js:1          GET https://unpkg.com/dash-bio@1.0.1/dash_bio/async-alignment.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

When visiting the link, I can see that the requested JS does not exist:

`Cannot find "/dash_bio/async-alignment.js" in dash-bio@1.0.1`

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to a library error. After talking to the Plolty staff, they made a new patched version which now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've just pasted your code into a MWE dash app. This works without issues in my environment.

- Are you running behind any firewalls that block unauthorised URLs?
- assuming you are using **dash_bio** 1.0.1
- does this work as a MWE outside **django** in your environment?
- looked into **django_plotly_dash** and found it does not work with **dash** 2.+

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash
import dash_bio as dashbio

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = dash.html.Div(
    [
        dash.html.Pre("hello"),
        dashbio.Ideogram(
            id="ideogram-id",
            chromosomes=["X"],
            orientation="horizontal",
        ),
    ]
)

app.run_server(mode="inline")
```